# Volvo V40 Immobilizer

Tags: volvo, v40

I bought a 02 V40. It is just a regular driver when I got it. The previous owner had lost the keys and the fob. So I have ordered a factory cylinder and key replacement. I had already removed and replaced the ignition switch. When I attempted to start the car with the new ignition switch, all lights on the dash lite up. There was one I was familiar with. A crossed out image of the car. It was blinking.

I joined the Volvo clubs and organizations, asked about this and have no explanation why that lights is on. I know the new keys came with new codes. These items are from authorized Volvo factories. Well, any reasonable explanation would be appreciated. The Volvo organizations have yet to respond to date.

Comment: I think you have to use a reader/writer to match / code the new items to the car - someone may have one on the forum or you need to go to a dealer.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You may also find a locksmith who can do it for you as well. Without an original key (read: already programmed), most cars will not allow you to register a new one into the system without extraordinary means.

Answer (score 1):

The key(s) will need programming to the car using a diagnostic scanner or key programer. Technically the cars ECU or immobiliser module needs to be programmed to match the keys rather than the keys themselves being programmed.

The dealer will obviously be able to do it but you will probably get a much better price using a independent specialist or auto electrician, you will probably find a mobile auto locksmith. Every car that I know of with 'chipped' keys need to be programmed even if ordered from the dealer.

Comment: Actually most immobilizers systems since early 2000s do need to write data to the key in  order to program. Simple way to explain it is the Key has an ID that gets written and stored in immobilizer. Then the immobilizer writes an encrypted password on to the transponder(in key) itself.